Infinite loop occurs when a merge statement is entered with pyodbc
I am currently implementing an API using AWS Lambda to insert data into a SQL Server database.
I'm using Python 3.11.
The code executes successfully and returns a 200 status code,
but when I run a SELECT query in SSMS,
it results in an infinite execution.
I need help resolving this issue.
Here is my code:
conn_str = (
        f'Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};'
        f'Database=TMP;'
        f'Encrypt=no;'
    )
    data = [{
        "sfid" : "aws1123124",
        "lastmodifieddate" : "a551231",
        "comments" : "a11231",
        "keyword" : "a41231231",
        "productcode" : "s55234234",
        "serialNumber" : "d1123123"
    }]
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
    try :
        for record in data:
                print("in record")
                print(record['sfid'])
                merge_sql = """
                MERGE INTO [dbo].[LocalDB] AS Target
                USING (SELECT ? AS sfid, ? AS lastmodifieddate, ? AS comments, ? AS keyword, ? AS productcode, ? AS serialNumber) AS Source
                ON Target.sfid = Source.sfid
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                    UPDATE SET 
                        lastmodifieddate = Source.lastmodifieddate, 
                        comments = Source.comments, 
                        keyword = Source.keyword, 
                        productcode = Source.productcode, 
                        serialNumber = Source.serialNumber
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (sfid, lastmodifieddate, comments, keyword, productcode, serialNumber)
                    VALUES (Source.sfid, Source.lastmodifieddate, Source.comments, Source.keyword, Source.productcode, Source.serialNumber);
                """
                cursor.execute(merge_sql, 
                               record['sfid'], 
                               record['lastmodifieddate'], 
                               record['comments'], 
                               record['keyword'],
                               record['productcode'],
                               record['serialNumber'])
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        cursor.execute("ROLLBACK")
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        raise e
    finally:
        if cursor is not None:
            try:
                cursor.close()
            except Exception as ex:
                print(f"Error closing cursor: {ex}")
        
        if conn is not None:
            try:
                conn.close()
            except Exception as ex:
                print(f"Error closing connection: {ex}")

    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }


"when I run a SELECT query in SSMS, it results in an infinite execution" This suggests that something is locking the rows, and so you cannot read them. You might be better off using disposable objects, if I am honest; the cursor.execute("ROLLBACK") has a "smell" to it. Also some recommend reading on MERGE.

Shouldn't it be cursor.commit() within the for? Also you don't need to define an explicit transaction (cursor.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION"); PyODBC does that automagically. That you don't have an cursor.execute("COMMIT;") is likely why you have a hanging transaction.

cursor.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")... conn.commit()? Consistency may help.

Wouldn't this code (and i use the term loosely) actually create a non-closed transaction? because conn explicitly opened one, and then you increase it to two with BEGIN TRAN while conn.commit() decrease it to one level again. Just remove BEGIN TRAN

I simply changed your code to remove cursor.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION") and cursor.execute("ROLLBACK"), and then changed conn.commit() to cursor.commit() and moved it inside the try. I also, as suggested in the linked list of articles added a HOLDLOCK hint to the MERGE (though, again, ideally use an upsert). This is condensed intentionally, but this effectively becomes:
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
try :
    for record in data:
        print("in record")
        print(record['sfid'])
        merge_sql = """
        MERGE INTO [dbo].[LocalDB] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS Target 
        ...
        """
        cursor.execute(merge_sql, 
                       record['sfid'], 
                       record['lastmodifieddate'], 
                       record['comments'], 
                       record['keyword'],
                       record['productcode'],
                       record['serialNumber'])
        cursor.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    raise e
finally:
...

